# Removing the error element from a list of a list using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

## Goal

Removing the `error` element and combining all the columns of a nested dataframe using `purrr` package. Please guide me what functions can I use to get the desired output.

## Sample data

I have uploaded a small subset of the data that you can find here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsMFpkDhWcnw7xvU4JLg1Al9AqzA

You can load it: `load(file = here::here("data", "raw_data", "veh.Rda"))`
And then:
`ds_mainline_nested_acc <- veh`

## Nested Data

I have the following results from a model fit:

```
ds_mainline_nested_acc <- ds_mainline %>% 
  group_by(file.ID2, LV, chunk_of_speed) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(acc_mps2.ED = furrr::future_map(data, safely(find_acc), .progress = TRUE)) 

> ds_mainline_nested_acc
# A tibble: 2,676 x 5
   file.ID2 LV      chunk_of_speed data                   acc_mps2.ED
   <chr>    <chr>            <dbl> <list>                 <list>     
 1 Cars_01  WhiteC2              1 <tibble [1,857 x 148]> <list [2]> 
 2 Cars_01  WhiteC2              2 <tibble [1,856 x 148]> <list [2]> 
 3 Cars_01  WhiteC2              3 <tibble [1,856 x 148]> <list [2]> 
 4 Cars_01  WhiteC2              4 <tibble [1,856 x 148]> <list [2]> 
 5 Cars_01  WhiteC2              5 <tibble [1,857 x 148]> <list [2]> 
 6 Cars_01  Ford1                1 <tibble [549 x 148]>   <list [2]> 
 7 Cars_01  Ford1                2 <tibble [549 x 148]>   <list [2]> 
 8 Cars_01  Ford1                3 <tibble [549 x 148]>   <list [2]> 
 9 Cars_01  Ford1                4 <tibble [549 x 148]>   <list [2]> 
10 Cars_01  Ford1                5 <tibble [549 x 148]>   <list [2]> 
# ... with 2,666 more rows
```

### List structure

```
> ds_mainline_nested_acc %>% select(-data) %>% transpose() %>% simplify_all() %>% str(list.len = 4)
List of 2676
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ file.ID2      : chr "Cars_01"
  ..$ LV            : chr "WhiteC2"
  ..$ chunk_of_speed: num 1
  ..$ acc_mps2.ED   :List of 2
  .. ..$ result:'data.frame':   1857 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Time       : num [1:1857] 383 383 383 383 383 ...
  .. .. ..$ acc_mps2.ED: num [1:1857] 0.0515 0.0515 0.0515 0.0515 0.0515 ...
  .. ..$ error : NULL
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ file.ID2      : chr "Cars_01"
  ..$ LV            : chr "WhiteC2"
  ..$ chunk_of_speed: num 2
  ..$ acc_mps2.ED   :List of 2
  .. ..$ result:'data.frame':   1856 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Time       : num [1:1856] 414 414 414 414 414 ...
  .. .. ..$ acc_mps2.ED: num [1:1856] 0.646 0.646 0.646 0.646 0.646 ...
  .. ..$ error : NULL
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ file.ID2      : chr "Cars_01"
  ..$ LV            : chr "WhiteC2"
  ..$ chunk_of_speed: num 3
  ..$ acc_mps2.ED   :List of 2
  .. ..$ result:'data.frame':   1856 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Time       : num [1:1856] 445 445 445 445 445 ...
  .. .. ..$ acc_mps2.ED: num [1:1856] -0.395 -0.395 -0.395 -0.395 -0.395 ...
  .. ..$ error : NULL
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ file.ID2      : chr "Cars_01"
  ..$ LV            : chr "WhiteC2"
  ..$ chunk_of_speed: num 4
  ..$ acc_mps2.ED   :List of 2
  .. ..$ result:'data.frame':   1856 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Time       : num [1:1856] 476 476 476 476 476 ...
  .. .. ..$ acc_mps2.ED: num [1:1856] -0.534 -0.534 -0.534 -0.534 -0.534 ...
  .. ..$ error : NULL
  [list output truncated]
```

## What I need to do

The `acc_mps2.Ed` list column contains a list in each row. The list contains the `result` and `error` elements. The `result` element is a dataframe containing 2 columns. I want to get the final output with the following columns:

```
file.ID2 LV      chunk_of_speed Time                   acc_mps2.ED
```

Essentially, I want to get rid of the `error` element and combine all the columns of the `data` and `acc_mps2.ED` list.

## What I tried

I have read so many blogposts so far but still can't figure out how to remove the `error` element and combine the columns. I have also tried different `purrr` functions. For example:

```
> ds_mainline_nested_acc %>% transpose() %>% simplify_all() %>% compact() %>% unlist() %>% head()
$file.ID2
[1] "Cars_01"

$LV
[1] "WhiteC2"

$chunk_of_speed
[1] 1

$data.file.ID1
[1] "Cars_20160601_01.hdf5"

$data.file.ID2
[1] "Cars_20160601_01.hdf5"

$data.file.ID3
[1] "Cars_20160601_01.hdf5"
```

Obviously, the result is not in the dataframe output. I also tried:

```
> ds_mainline_nested_acc %>% transpose() %>% simplify_all() %>% compact() %>% map_df(.$acc_mps2.ED)
Error: Can't convert NULL to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

What am I missing? Isn't `compact()` supposed to remove the `NULL` values? Please guide me what functions can I use to get the desired output?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] of your data and an example of desired output? Do you want one  dataframe with 1 row for each list item and the 5 columns you list under "What I need to do". If so, how should we turn the 1856 values in Time and acc_mps2.ED into a single value? Should they stay as a nested list? Paste together into a comma separated string?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to add a reproducible dataset but creating it from this data is taking very long. The main outputs that I want to get are the 2 vectors `Time` and `acc_mps2.ED` from the `acc_mps2.ED` list. The corresponding `file.ID2`, `LV` and `chunk_of_speed` repeat. Thus, each row contains a unique value of `Time` and `acc_mps2.ED`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could upload the Rdata file perhaps? Using as few data entries as possible?

Comment: @erocoar Thank you. I have uploaded a sample data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a simple solution: First you map over the `acc_mps2.ED` column to select only the `results`. Next, you map over that column plus the `data` column to `cbind` them, and then you remove the data column.

```
library(tidyverse)
ds_mainline_nested_acc  %>%
  mutate(
    acc_mps2.ED = pmap(
      ds_mainline_nested_acc  %>% 
        select("acc_mps2.ED", "data"),
      ~ bind_cols(..1$result, ..2))
  ) %>%
  select(-data)
```

`purrr`'s `pmap` allows you to iterate over multiple things at once (so `..1` and `..2` actually select the respective columns)

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't get rid of the error items. I get following when I run your code on the complete data: `Error: Evaluation error: Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a simpleError/error/condition`

Comment: That's odd, does it work when you run it on the data set that you uploaded here? If yes you'd need to post more details on the complete data set :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand that the data might not be representative. I have modified the code as follows and it works for me: `ds_mainline_nested_acc  %>%
  mutate(
    acc_mps2.ED = map(acc_mps2.ED, ~ .x$result)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  mutate(TYPE = map(acc_mps2.ED, class)) %>% 
  unnest(.preserve = acc_mps2.ED) %>% 
  filter(TYPE == "data.frame") %>% 
  unnest()`